# Rails calling a javascript function from a user defined class

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a custom class named **NotificationManager** in which i have defined a method, **update_notification**. I want to call a javascript function inside this method. I have tried using the **respond_to** method and, since it is not a controller action, it can not be called there.

This is my code.

```
class NotificationManager
   def update_notification
      //here i want to call a javascript function
   end
end
```

Comment: Where do you intend to use this method? In controller?

Comment: Yea. Infact , in the application_controller, one of the before_action method.

Comment: So could you tell me what will the javascript do? Since javascript is client-side, it may be not a good idea to call it before rendering the action. I think it could be achieved another way.

Comment: actually, the javascript has to add an 'li' to the notification dropdown. So that  on loading the page and on arriving new notifications, it can call that same javascript function.

Comment: Though I don't have the sample of your code, but I think it could be done easily by modifying the dropdown's collection directly in ruby code instead?